# Debugger in Visual Studio Code displays cryptic error window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up Visual Studio code for C++, as this video shows:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIw02CaEusY&t=701s .  The problem I am running into is when configuring the debugger,

I get a strange error window whenever I try to debug the project:

> "The preLaunchTask 'g++.exe build active file' terminated with error
>   code 1".

I have tried researching the error and nothing useful shows up.  I have tried searching similar issues on StackOverflow without much luck.

This is the code in my tasks.json file:

```
    {
       "version": "2.0.0",
       "tasks": [
           {
               "label": "echo",
               "type": "shell",
               "command": "g++ -g main.cpp",
               "group": {
                   "kind": "build",
                   "isDefault": true
               }
           },
           {
               "type": "shell",
               "label": "g++.exe build active file",
               "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
               "args": [
                   "-g",
                   "${file}",
                   "-o",
                   "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
               ],
               "options": {
                   "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
               }
           }
       ]
   }
```

and this is my launch.json file:

```
      "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": false,
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ],
                "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Did the compile succeed? Do you have an executable?

Comment: Is it the only error that you see in the output window?

Comment: Your `exe` file name does not match between the two json files. I mean `"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` versus `"${workspaceFolder}/a.exe"` that is unless your `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` is `a`

Comment: Try running g++ in the terminal window.

Comment: @allenlswain I don't expect anyone to have a definite answer without your input.

Comment: @dreschmerjm it does compile, but nothing shows up in the output window.  I'm new to coding, but I would expect the "Hello World" to be there.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé There are no errors in the output window.  This appears as a pop-up.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried making them the same in both files, trying both paths, and I still got the error.  (Also, sorry for the delay in responses.  I certainly appreciate all the help).